# Backing up a linux setup (snapshot?)

Tags: linux, backup, vps

I've got a VPS. I wish to downgrade its plan. But, according to the provider, I'll have to set it up again, which, I think, would be time consuming.

Is there anything I could do to backup my current setup, download it on my drive, downgrade, upload the backup on new system and restore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), all global settings are stored in `/etc` and `/usr/local/etc/`.

User data and settings are stored in `/home/user_name` for regular users and `/root` for root.

Service data, like web pages, may be stored in `/var` or somewhere else, you better know your environment.

You have to backup up it all. Also you need to save list of software repositories and list of installed packages(this is things are specific for each linux distrib).

Install clear system. Restore repositories settings. Update avaliable package index. Install all packages from saved list. Restore settings and service data. You have completely the same system.

For example, in Debian/Ubuntu:

Save `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` for repositories.

Save `dpkg --get-selections > packages_list` for packages list.

Install new system. Restore repositories settings.

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
dpkg --set-selections < packages_list
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Now you may restore settings and data.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm on CentOS. @Selivanov

Comment: For CentOS you have repositories settings in`/etc/yum` instead of `/etc/apt`. Saving list of installed packages and restoring them is described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-get-list-installed-software-reinstallation-restore.html). All other steps are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to boot from some Linux LiveCD on VPS, you may just backup your whole installation with tar:

```
tar -cvpfz /backup/fullbackup.tar.gz --directory=/ --exclude=proc \
--exclude=sys --exclude=dev --exclude=backup .
```

Then copy it over ssh or ftp to your machine. Downgrade VPS, boot from LiveCD again, create new partitions with the same arrangement, mount your new root partition to `/mnt/root`, mount all other partitions to corresponding subdirectories in root partition: new `/var` partition to `/mnt/root/var` and so on. Upload your backup to VPS and restore it:

```
tar -xvpfz /mnt/root/backup/fullbackup.tar.gz --directory /mnt/root
```

Fix /mnt/root/fstab. Restore the boot loader. Reboot and check if everything is OK.